# OnClick listener - one function for all clicks

Tags: android

In my layout xml file I have set the android:onClick attribute for a Button element to a function in my activity.  So when I click the button the function is called with a View as its argument.  Are there any information in that View argument that has the id of the button being clicked?  I'm trying to figure out if I have to have one onClick function for every element or if I can use one function and switch depending on the id of the element being clicked.

Comment: Tried using the getId()-method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
switch (v.getID) { 
case R.id.A:
 .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ohh Apps has the answer all right... just for throughness I have something like so...
case sensitive stuff.... funny how a getID won't work while a getId will be golden...  funny how a compiler couldn't do a "sloppy check" and correct such case issues.

like so

```
View myButton = findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
     myButton.setOnClickListener(this); 
  View myOtherButton = findViewById(R.id.myotherbutton);
       myOtherButton.setOnClickListener(this); 
public void onClick(View v) {
             switch (v.getId()) {
           case R.id.mybutton:  
                              //Do something related to the mybutton click

            break;
        case R.id.myotherbutton:    
                              //Do something related to the myotherbutton click

            break;
       //chain all Resource ID's here like above.... 
                                   }
}
```

you must also not to forget to setup a Onclick listener for every click event before the switch or the case will never get resolved....

//whoo hoo.  8cupsaday android app coming soon!